# Add a separate category to the impact section to count non-Stack Overflow users

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think it's good to have a count of non-Stack Overflow users because they are the general people who are seeking for answers. This count will tell us a how much questions or answers are impact on general people. Also can we introduce a new badge for if a user reached for certain level of general people who surfing the Internet for seeking answers.

Answer (score 8):

The IMPACT PEOPLE REACHED stat/number is already based on non-logged in users and account-less users.

The people reached stat is pretty much based entirely on how many times the page was viewed. [Read here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here). So it doesn't take into account whether a logged-in user is viewing the page or if it's a non-logged in user. They all count the same, 1 page view.

So the current stat already shows us/includes the account-less users.

I don't think there would be any benefit in separating page views by logged-in and not logged-in users.